# Can you bind parameters before preparing the SQL? PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

My normal sequence of interacting with my database is something like this:

```
$sql = "select count(*) from users where username = :newusername";
$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":newusername", $newUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

...prepare is called before bindParam. Can I prepare the SQL after my bindParams or wouldn't that work? This would be handy for this logic:

```
$sql = "update users set suspended = :newsuspensionsetting";
$statement->bindParam(":newsuspensionsetting", $newSuspensionSetting, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($newUsernameHasBeenSet) {
    $sql .= ", username = :newusername";
    $statement->bindParam(":newusername", $newUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

if ($newPasswordHasBeenSet) {
    $newPassword = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql .= ", password = :newpassword";
    $statement->bindParam(":newpassword", $newPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$sql .= "where permanent_id = :permanentidofusertochange";
$statement->bindParam(":permanentidofusertochange", $permanentIDOfUserToChange, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

thanks

Comment: Well as values are bound to place holders in the prepared statement, the answer is NO

Comment: Build an array of values, then process the array to make the binds after you have built and prepared the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould create an associative array and add values in it, if the condition is satisfied :
you should have something like this inside of your if:

`$arr += ["keytobind"=>"value"]`

When all of your "ifs" are passed, then, you use the prepare statement with your prepare method.

Finally, use a :
 `foreach($arr as $key=>$value){$statement->bindParam(":".$key,$value); }`